# Какими могут быть условия в конструкции if?

Tags: php, if

Ну понятно что могут быть условия типа a > b, a >= b, a + b = c, и так далее, а что-то ещё можно писать? Вот например мне надо написать - если адрес страницы, на который находится этот код, такой-то, то выводить то-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/somewhere/") {
print "selected";
}
```

или

```
print ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/somewhere/") ? 'selected' : '';
```

Comment: лучше по имени ссылки файл подключить, чем на каждую страницу условие (или свитч) писать.

Answer (score 4):

В условии if() можно писать любые математические выражения, не только условные.

```
if ($a % $b)
if ($a = $b+$c)
if ($a++)
if (++$a)
if ($a >> $b)
if ($a === $b)
if ($a !== $b)
if ($res = mysql_fetch($sqlRes))
```

Дока по if:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Условие if работает так: оно проверяет результат выражения внутри скобок на предмет равенства TRUE или FALSE. Если результат имеет тип, отличный от Boolean, то сперва происходит конвертация в Boolean.

Дока по приведению к булевому типу:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

При преобразовании в логический тип, следующие значения рассматриваются как FALSE:

- Сам булев FALSE
- целое 0 (ноль)
- число с плавающей точкой 0.0 (ноль)
- пустая строка и строка "0"
- пустой массив
- объект без атрибутов (только PHP4)
- специальный тип NULL (включая неустановленные переменные)

Все остальные значения рассматриваются как TRUE (включая любой ресурс).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp